# scipy.optimize.minimize with general array indexing

Tags: optimization, pandas, indexing, scipy, minimize

I want to solve an optimization problem with the method 'COBYLA' in scipy.optimize.minimize as follows:

```
test = spopt.minimize(testobj, x_init, method='COBYLA', constraints=cons1)
y = test.x
print 'solution x =', y
```

However, since the program is quite large, a scalable way to write the objective function (and the constraints) is to use a general index for the arguments. For example, if I could use `x['parameter1']` or `x.param1` instead of `x[0]`, then the program would be easier to read and debug. I tried both writing `x` as an object or a `pandas Series` with general indexing like `x['parameter1']`, as follows:

```
def testobj(x):
    return x['a']**2 + x['b'] + 1

def testcon1(x):
    return x['a']

def testcon2(x):
    return x['b']

def testcon3(x):
    return 1 - x['a'] - x['b']


x_init = pd.Series([0.1, 0.1])
x_init.index = ['a','b']

cons1 = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': testcon1}, \
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': testcon2}, \
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': testcon3})
```

but whenever I pass that into the `minimize` routine, it throws an error:

```
return x['a']**2 + x['b'] + 1
ValueError: field named a not found
```

It works perfectly if I use the normal numpy array. Perhaps I'm not doing it right, but is that a limitation of the minimize function that I have to use numpy array and not any other data structure? The scipy documentation on [this topic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) mentions that the initial guess has to be ndarray, but I'm curious how is the routine calling the arguments, because for `pandas Series` calling the variable with `x[0]` or `x['a']` are equivalent.

Comment: You could write an object wrapper for your parameter vector and use that in your computations.

Comment: As I go google for object wrapper, is there a small example that I can learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, scipy optimize uses numpy arrays as input, not pandas Series. When you initialize with a pandas series, it effectively converts it to an array and so you cannot access the fields by name anymore.

Probably the easiest way to go is to just create a function which re-wraps the parameters each time you call them; for example:

```
def make_series(params):
    return pd.Series(params, index=['a', 'b'])

def testobj(x):
    x = make_series(x)
    return x['a']**2 + x['b'] + 1

def testcon1(x):
    x = make_series(x)
    return x['a']

def testcon2(x):
    x = make_series(x)
    return x['b']

def testcon3(x):
    x = make_series(x)
    return 1 - x['a'] - x['b']

x_init = make_series([1, 1])
test = spopt.minimize(testobj, x_init, method='COBYLA', constraints=cons1)
print('solution x =', test.x)
# solution x = [  1.38777878e-17   0.00000000e+00]
```

Comment: but in a little different way. I stored the mapping of `'a'` and `'b'` to `0` and `1` in a pandas Series called `x_ind` (say), and calling the vector `x` with `x[x_ind['a']]`